# Using Python to control Brooks MFC Power Supply

Tags: voltage, python, flow-control

Is it possible to use Python to control the Brooks 0152/0154 power supply that powers and controls Brooks MFC units?

The [manual](http://www2.emersonprocess.com/siteadmincenter/PM%20Micro%20Motion%20Documents/Brooks-MC-541-C-052-AAG.pdf) mentions the pin outs of the `RS-232` ports, but nothing about how we can control the Brooks 0152/0154 through the RS-232 port.

[image]

Comment: From what device are you planning on controlling this device from?

Comment: @Alex I'm planning to use a PC (windows) to control this device through an Arduino Mega

Answer (score 0):

The manual says under section 4:

> For operation of the application software it is required to have the Brooks
>   Smart DDE software (version 1.1 or higher) running on the P.C.)
>   Version 1.1 of Smart DDE can operate without the software protection
>   key (dongle) when Interfacing with Model 0152/0154.

So I guess if you write a Python script that interacts with the Smart DDE you can communicate with the device. But their package is probably not for free...

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a standard serial port, then in principle, yes. However, if the protocol is not published, then you may need to reverse engineer it. Which should be legal for the purposes of interoperability.